# search (e.g. awk, grep, sed) for string, then look for X lines above and another string below

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, nawk

I need to be able to search for a string (lets use 4320101), print 20 lines above the string and print after this until it finds the string

For example:

```
Random text I do not want or blank line
16 Apr 2013 00:14:15
id="4320101"
</eventUpdate>
Random text I do not want or blank line
```

I just want the following result outputted to a file:

```
16 Apr 2013 00:14:15
id="4320101"
</eventUpdate>
```

There are multiple examples of these groups of text in a file that I want.

I tried using this below:

```
cat filename | grep "</eventUpdate>" -A 20 4320101 -B 100 > greptest.txt
```

But it only ever shows for 20 lines either side of the string.

Notes:
- the line number the text is on is inconsistent so I cannot go off these, hence why I am using -A 20.
 - ideally I'd rather have it so when it searches after the string, it stops when it finds  and then carries on searching.

Summary: find 4320101, output 20 lines above 4320101 (or one line of white space), and then output all lines below 4320101 up to

```
</eventUpdate>
```

Doing research I am unsure of how to get awk, nawk or sed to work in my favour to do this.

Comment: `-A` is the number of lines grep will print `A`fter the matched line. If you don't want any lines after the matched line, why are you asking for 20? Also I don't understand your comment about line numbers being inconsistent, but if you want 20 lines `B`efore, use `-B 20`

Comment: I see. This should work: cat filename | grep 4320101 -A 100 </eventUpdate> -B 20 , but it returns: </eventUpdate>: No such file or directory

Comment: I realise the way -A and -B works is that it wants value filename so it thinks eventUpdate is a file. However I want to just search up to eventUpdate (giving it 100 lines to find it below 4320101)

Comment: There isn't a standard tool to do this job.  I have a 70-line (non-minimal) Perl script that does lines before and after; it would have to modified to handle 'after until alternative pattern', but that is a lot easier than 'from specified pattern before 4320101'.  I also have a shell script version that uses `ed` (and `sed` and `sort` and `sed` again) on each file - that would be easiest to adapt.  Contact me (see my profile) if you want these; they're not fully worked solutions to your problem, but might be useful stepping stones to providing it.

Comment: What do you want to happen if 2 ranges overlap, e.g. if 2 occurrences of 4320101 lie within 20 lines of each other? Print all the lines once? Print the lines that lie within both ranges twice?

Comment: It only appears once within 20 lines above itself (that time being itself) and up to eventUpdate, which can never be 21 lines above the next occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/\n/&/20;tb;$!{N;ba};:b;/4320102/!D;:c;n;/<\/eventUpdate>/!bc' file
```

EDIT:

- `:a;s/\n/&/20;tb;$!{N;ba};` this keeps a window of 20 lines in the pattern space (PS)
- `:b;/4320102!D;` this moves the above window through the file until the pattern `4320102` is found.
- `:c;n;/<\/eventUpdate>/!bc` the 20 line window is printed and any subsequent line until the pattern  `<\/eventUpdate>` is found.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just altered it to check 3 lines, read for users input from read ID (in this case 4320102) and then do /'$ID' .I have to ask though, can you break down what all of that does exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly `awk` solution :)

```
awk 'BEGIN{last=1}
{if((length($0)==0) || (Random ~ $0))last=NR} 
/4320101/{flag=1;
if((NR-last)>20) last=NR-20;
cmd="sed -n \""last+1","NR-1"p \" input.txt";
system(cmd);
}
flag==1{print}
/eventUpdate/{flag=0}' <filename>
```

So basically what it does is keeps track of the last blank line or line containing `Random` pattern in the `last` variable. Now if the `4320101` has been found, it prints from `that line -20 or last` whichever is nearer through a `system sed` command. And sets the `flag`. The `flag` causes the next onwards lines to be printed till `eventUpdate` has been found. Have not tested though, but should be working

Answer (score 1):

Look-behind in sed/awk is always tricky.. This self contained `awk` script basically keeps the last 20 lines stored, when it gets to  `4320101` it prints these stored lines, up to the point where the blank or undesired line is found, then it stops. At that point it switches into `printall` mode and prints all lines until the `eventUpdate` is encountered, then it prints that and quits.

```
awk '
function store( line ) {
    for( i=0; i <= 20; i++ ) {
        last[i-1] = last[i]; i++;
    };
    last[20]=line;
};
function purge() {
    for( i=20; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        if( length(last[i])==0 || last[i] ~ "Random" ) {
            stop=i;
            break
        };
    };
    for( i=(stop+1); i <= 20; i++ ) {
        print last[i];
    };

};
{
store($0);
if( /4320101/ ) {
    purge();
    printall=1;
    next;
};
if( printall == 1) {
    print;
    if( /eventUpdate/ ) {
        exit 0;
    };
};
}' test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
awk '{ 
    a[NR] = $0
}

/<\/eventUpdate>/ { 
    x = NR
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        if (a[i]~/4320101/) {
            for (j=i-20;j<=x;j++) {
            print a[j]
            }
        }
    }
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand your requirements:

You have two strings, which I'll call `KEY` and `LIMIT`. And you want to print:

1. At most 20 lines before a line containing `KEY`, but stopping if there is a blank line.
2. All the lines between a line containing `KEY` and the following line containing `LIMIT`. (This ignores your requirement that there be no more than 100 such lines; if that's important, it's relatively straightforward to add.)

The easiest way to accomplish `(1)` is to keep a circular buffer of 20 lines, and print it out when you hit `key`. `(2)` is trivial in either sed or awk, because you can use the two-address form to print the range.

So let's do it in awk:

```
#file: extract.awk

# Initialize the circular buffer
BEGIN          { count = 0; }
# When we hit an empty line, clear the circular buffer
length() == 0  { count = 0; next; }
# When we hit `key`, print and clear the circular buffer
index($0, KEY) { for (i = count < 20 ? 0 : count - 20; i < count; ++i)
                   print buf[i % 20];
                 hi = 0;
               }
# While we're between key and limit, print the line
index($0, KEY),index($0, LIMIT)
               { print; next; }
# Otherwise, save the line
               { buf[count++ % 20] = $0; }
```

In order to get that to work, we need to set the values of `KEY` and `LIMIT`. We can do that on the command line:

```
awk -v "KEY=4320101" -v "LIMIT=</eventUpdate>" -f extract.awk $FILENAME
```

**Notes:**

1. I used `index($0, foo)` instead of the more usual `/foo/`, because it avoids having to escape regex special characters, and there is nowhere in the requirements that regexen are even desired. `index(haystack, needle)` returns the index of `needle` in `haystack`, with indices starting at `1`, or `0` if `needle` is not found. Used as a true/false value, it is true of `needle` is found.
2. `next` causes processing of the current line to end. It can be quite handy, as this little program shows.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use 2 passes of the file - the first to identify the line numbers in the range within which your target regexp is found, the second to print the lines in the selected range, e.g.:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    if ($0 ~ /\<4320101\>/ {
        for (i=NR-20;i<NR;i++)
            range[i]
        inRange = 1
    }
    if (inRange) {
        range[NR]
    }
    if ($0 ~ /<\/eventUpdate>/) {
        inRange = 0
    }
    next
}
FNR in range
' file file
```

Comment: Using this I got: awk: cmd. line:9: (FILENAME=test FNR=482) fatal: attempt to use scalar `inRange' as array

Comment: fixed. awk did point you to the line where the error was and tell you what the error was.