# print the four lines above the sed/awk start expression

Tags: bash, awk, sed, ksh

I have the following sed command that fetches back a whole chunk of a log that has an `<interface>` XML within it that's being printed into a txt file:

```
sed -n '/(StartingExpression)/{:start /<\/Interface>/!{N;b start};/(SomeValueInTheXML)"/p}' *.log > File.txt
```

The issue is that I have some dynamic values (time stamp) that's always 4 lines above the `(StartingExpression)`... is there a way to print something like:

```
line of (StartingExpression) -4
```

?

I found this question:
[search (e.g. awk, grep, sed) for string, then look for X lines above and another string below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694469/search-e-g-awk-grep-sed-for-string-then-look-for-x-lines-above-and-another) but the solution isn't really clear :\

Thanks for the help.

also, if anyone has a good source to learn sed, I'll be thankful if you post it :)

EDIT per request:

```
one
two
1/1/2015
line 1
12345
(StartingExpression)
<Interface>
   <A>
   Name=Andy
   </A>
</Interface>
three
four
1/1/2015
line 1
12345
(StartingExpression)
<Interface>
   <A>
   Name=John
   </A>
</Interface>
hello
world
```

I would like to print from `1/1/2015` (which is 3 lines above `(StartingExpression)` - this can be dynamic as its a date ) until `</Interface>`

EDIT: I forgot to mention, there can be multiple instances of these interfaces... How do you also ensure to print ONLY the one that has `Name=Andy`?

file.txt:

```
1/1/2015
line 1
12345
(StartingExpression)
<Interface>
   <A>
   Name=Andy
   </A>
</Interface>
```

Comment: keep the last 4 previous line in holding buffer (with `h`, `H` or `x`) and add it when before printing (`g`, `G`or `x`) result (need reformat like standard line). Awk is certainly more adequat in this case). It help if there is some data sample, not only the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` idiom will print n lines preceding and including pattern.

```
$awk -v n="$plines" '{a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n} /pattern/{for(i=p;i<p+n;i++) print a[i%n]}' file
```

For example

```
$awk -v n=5 '{a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n} /20/{for(i=p;i<p+n;i++) print a[i%n]}' <(seq 10 99)

16
17
18
19
20
```

UPDATE for additional logic.

You can incorporate printing after pattern match easily as well.  This script will print the lines before; and now after the match until the end of close tag.

```
$ awk -v n=4 '           {a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n} 
   /(StartingExpression)/{for(i=p;i<p+n-1;i++) print a[i%n];f=1} 
                        f{print} 
            /\/Interface/{exit}' file

1/1/2015
line 1
12345
(StartingExpression)
<Interface>
   <A>
   </A>
</Interface>
```

UPDATE: filter based on attribute value

It's easier at this point just pass through another script instead of rewriting it.  Replace the exit with f=0, the first script will output all the matching records and filter in a second script the record of interest.

```
$ awk -v n=4 '           {a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n}
   /(StartingExpression)/{for(i=p;i<p+n-1;i++) print a[i%n];f=1}
                        f{print}
            /\/Interface/{f=0}' file
| awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="</Interface>\n"} 
 /Name=Andy/'


1/1/2015
line 1
12345
(StartingExpression)
<Interface>
   <A>
   Name=Andy
   </A>
</Interface>
```

Comment: I get what you did... What about the `(SomeValueInTheXML)` part? I am trying to ensure that I print only the XML (out of many duplicate XMLs with different values but same pattern) that has a specific value in it...

what you have here is a value as pattern rather than an object (or in my case an XML)... how do I go about ensuring that anything between and including `(StartingExpression)` and `</Interface>` as well as the four lines before `(StartingExpression)`

Comment: `awk` is a better alternative than `sed` for anything complicated.  It doesn't have cryptic single letter codes as `sed` so you may need to type more but it's readable.

Comment: Hi... You're going to kill me. I added another condition that I just realized I missed... Mind taking a look once more? I just need to figure out where I add this last condition in. Also, thanks a ton... you've been insanely helpful here and in other questions I've asked!

Comment: what does the $0 in a[p]=$0 stand for? I know that $0, $1, $2, etc are arguments... what if $0 is occupied?

Comment: $0 is the whole line, $1, $2, etc are the fields separated by FS.

Comment: Ok something isn't right... to run this script I essentially run this:

`./Script.sh ${CustIDInput} GET_CUSTOMER_INFO`

what ends up happening is that $0 gets the following value: `./Script.sh`  why's that?

Comment: its the file that contains the awk... I need to run it as an independent script rather than the command itself.

Comment: I think argument substitution is not correct in your script.  Without knowing what it is difficult to diagnose.

Comment: From my understanding, in ksh $0 = script name... is $0 different in awk? maybe I need to create an awk script that's independent of the ksh script this command is in...?

Comment: Hi... how would I go about to write this as an independent awk script? `#!/usr/bin/awk -f -k` and then what comes in the parenthesis? I'm still stuck trying to get an XML block with a specific value in it and the four rows above it :\

Comment: there are two awk scripts there; probably easier this way.  You can copy each to its own file and run it similarly piping one output to the next.

Comment: figured it out (hopefully) thanks again for all your trouble! expect some more questions from me soon ;) (at least I know there's someone here that knows awk properly!)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a grep version that supports -A and -B, and your file is made with fixed lines, you can use

```
grep -A2 -B6 "Name=Andy" request
```

Using your vi-knowledge can help for making the following command:

```
echo "/(StartingExpression)/-3,/<.Interface>/ p" | ed -s request
```

I used a `.` for the slash in , I did not want to escape the character. This will only work when Andy is the first name.

Making it working with Andy somewhere else becomes more tricky:

```
rm /tmp/andy
echo "/Name=Andy/
?(StartingExpression)
-3,/<.Interface>/ w /tmp/andy" | ed -s request 2>&1 >/dev/null
cat /tmp/andy
rm /tmp/andy
```